# Solving a trigonometric equation for the angle in degrees

Tags: equation-solving

I am having problems with this equation:

$\qquad 0=0.0012\cos^2 (\theta)-0.0008\sin^2 (\theta)$

How should I write the code in Mathematica so I can solve for $θ$ in degrees? I have tried a lot of things but none of them worked.

Comment: Try this `(\[Theta] /. 
   FindRoot[
    0.0012 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 \[Minus] 0.0008 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 == 
     0, {\[Theta], 1}])/Degree` this is one of the many solutions, see plot of this function `Plot[0.0012 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 \[Minus] 
  0.0008 Sin[\[Theta]]^2, {\[Theta], -5, 5}]`

Answer (score 3):

The are many ways to go about solving your equation for `θ` in degrees. One of them is

```
NSolve[0.0012 Cos[θ Degree]^2 - 0.0008 Sin[θ Degree]^2 == 0, θ]
```

[image: msg]

> `{{θ -> -129.232}, {θ -> -50.7685}, {θ -> 50.7685}, {θ -> 129.232}}`

The message is issued because there are actually an infinite number of solutions. The ones returned are the four closest to the origin. We can see this is so by looking at the following plot.

```
Plot[0.0012 Cos[θ Degree]^2 - 0.0008 Sin[θ Degree]^2, {θ, -180, 180}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

You may gain more insight to the problem by converting your decimal multipliers to rational fractions, to let Mathematica go as far as it can.

```
eqn = 0 == 3/2 Cos[0]^2 - Sin[0]^2
```

You can get the radian solutions via Solve[ ], using the `C[1]->0` rule to handle the infinite number of potential solutions (try the command without it) and the `//Flatten` to clean up the output.

```
( Solve[eqn, 0] /. C[1] -> 0 ) //Flatten

(*{
θ -> -ArcTan[Sqrt[3/2]], 
θ -> π - ArcTan[Sqrt[3/2]], 
θ -> ArcTan[Sqrt[3/2]], 
θ -> -π + ArcTan[Sqrt[3/2]]
}  *)
```